# Smart ESC controlled over UART/SPI/I2C, to control an e bike wheel at very low speed

Tags: motor-controller

I work on a project for wheelchair users with only on functioning hand, I want to put a e-bike wheel, so a sensored hub motor, on the other side that mimics the speed of the functioning hand's wheel. My idea is to measure the speed of the user's moving wheel and try to match it with the other side (don't worry I know that I need to implement a turning functionality too :) ).

My problem is that I need an ESC that will run the wheel at low speeds, a few RPMs (using the e-bike wheel's hall sensor) and gets its control signal from a communication protocol be it UART or SPI or I2C, it does not really matter, in form of an RPM setpoint that is has to reach so not the basic RC ESCs, a quite "intelligent" one, do you know if this type of ESC exists? The power consumption will be maximum 150W-200W

Comment: `do you konw if this type of ESC exist ?` ... what use is a `yes` answer? ... please ask about the ESC, not about people's awareness of the existence of the ESC

Answer (score 0):

A speed controller is not enough. You need position *and* speed control, so that one wheel is a "follower" of another wheel.

Such systems are commonly called "electronic gearing": there's an encoder on one wheel, and a servo motor with encoder on another wheel, and a servo drive implementing the gearing. Since the motor will turn much faster than the wheel, due to the reduction necessary, the gear ratio is not 1:1.

Instead of using a hub-powered bike wheel that suffers from poor controllability at low speeds, I'd use something that offers natural gearing. For example, a small "hoverboard-style" hub-motor wheel friction-coupled to the other wheelchair wheel.

The controller will still need to perform the gearing, but at least the motor is cheap and will have a much easier job.

There also needs to be steering input from somewhere, as the user won't be able to provide differential directional control - as both wheels will be "doing the same thing" by default.

Since most ESCs are not designed for servo-like position control, you may be better off getting a small DC-powered self contained servo motor with built-in servo drive - available from many sources nowadays (Teknic is one), and sticking a friction drive wheel on the shaft. Such motors need some configuration to do what you want, and they'll usually take the master encoder signals as control inputs, and DC power, and will act as followers at a given gear ratio.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just looked up the ClearPath servo from Teknic and its in fact a very convenient all in one solution, that could fit my needs.